# executing Linux commands inside a python script on my PI

Tags: python

I have a python script to send me an email when i detect motion from my noir Pi camera, which is been successfully called.

I know the script is being called, as i get the email on movement; but the script doesn't copy the jpgs from `/mnt/` to `/home/pi/box/pi_pictures`

Have i got the `subprocess.call` syntax correct at the bottom of this script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib
import subprocess


from email.mime.text import MIMEText

USERNAME = "theemailaddressisendfrom.com"
PASSWORD = "mypassword"
MAILTO  = "myemailaddress.com"

msg = MIMEText('blar blar')
msg['Subject'] = 'from pi script test1'
msg['From'] = USERNAME
msg['To'] = MAILTO

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
server.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(USERNAME, MAILTO, msg.as_string())
server.quit()


time.sleep(20)
subprocess.call("cp /mnt/*.jpg  /home/pi/box/pi_pictures", shell=True)
```

Comment: When you are looking into the the /mnt directory can you see you jpg files doing a ls command or are they in a sub directory ?

Comment: I can see them in the /mnt directory( no sub directory). the command "cp /mnt/*.jpg  /home/pi/box/pi_pictures" works from the command line, but not from the python script.

Comment: If you are seeing them then maybe try to catch the output of the command execution calling subprocess_check_output function (if you are using python version > 2.7 )

`subprocess.check_output(['cp', '/mnt/*.jpg','/home/pi/box/pi_pictures'])`

Comment: subprocess.check_output(['cp', '/mnt/*.jpg','/home/pi/box/pi_pictures']) doesn't work either

Comment: I always use `subprocess.call("cp /mnt/*.jpg  /home/pi/box/pi_pictures", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`. Maybe this helps. Otherwise try adding the full path of `cp`, So `"/bin/cp /mnt..."`

Comment: i tried **subprocess.call("cp /mnt/*.jpg  /home/pi/box/pi_pictures", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)** but still no luck.  I must be doing something very wrong! The script is sending a mail, but not copping the files.

Comment: As what user are you running the script (could be a permission issue)? Does something like `subprocess.call("touch /tmp/testing.txt", shell=True)` work?

Comment: thanks Gerben, but i made a syntax error as described below. I forgot to include **import time**. It now works from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Iv'e just found out what was wrong,

the script was hanging at `time.sleep(20)` because i didn't have `import time` at the top.

Oops!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the wildcard `*.jpg` in there messing it all up. If you're using that you have to run it with the `shell=True`. At that point the first argument must be a single line, like you have it. Breaking it down into an array will result in the `*` being treated as a literal and the different file names won't be inserted instead. You can try adding

```
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
```

to get some output from the command.

If you don't specifically need the capability of subprocess, it may be worth trying to use

```
os.system("cp /mnt/*.jpg  /home/pi/box/pi_pictures")
```

instead.

Comment: I tried adding 1) **import os** at top and 2) **os.system("cp /mnt/*.jpg  /home/pi/box/pi_pictures")** at end, but still didn't work.

Comment: the cp = coppy, is not part of the path, i assumed people knew that